# Does Seattle tenant enjoy the right of first order when rental is for sale?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, tenant

In Seattle, can I enjoy the "Right of first order" (ROR) to buy, when the property I am renting, is put up for sale?

Comment: Are you asking if this is in some kind of law in Seattle? I would assume it is just like any other real-estate dealing, you tender an offer and the seller accepts/rejects it. Are you asking if you need to be notified and given the option before the house is publicly available?

Comment: Is ROR in your lease?

Comment: As a side note: I haven't seen a mention of a "right of first order" anywhere, but I have seen "right of first offer" and "right of first refusal"...not sure if that terminology may help you at all, or if its merely pedantry...

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, curious whether I need to be notified before official sale.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you will get is the first-in-time ordinance passed by the city, but that was overturned in court. That law required accepting the first qualified applicant for a rental: it did not say anything about sales. If there is a specific provision to that effect in your lease agreement, that would be applicable, but there is no general legal mechanism that forces a seller to accept a particular offer.